# Jquery append is not working in ie

Tags: jquery, append

I am using jquery to append div onclick event but it is not working in ie at though it is working fine is firefox , chrome and safari here is my code

```
$('#start-chat').live("click",function(){
    $(this).parent('.click').append('<div id="forclick">some data inside it</div>');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `#start-chat`? What is `.click`? Is this element allowed to have `div` inside? Make sure that you create valid HTML.

Comment: Does .parent('.click') return a block element (like div etc)?

Comment: @Shanon -- can you show your html as well?

Comment: @Shanon What version of JQuery are you using, and what version of IE is it failing in?

Comment: are you getting any errors ? is your html valid ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.parents(...)` instead of `.parent(...)`

Comment: This could make their problem worse if there are other parent elements with the click class on them. .parents(...) climbs up the entire DOM tree. Here's an example of how that would fail http://jsfiddle.net/GgVpS/22/ .

Answer (score 0):

by way of the code you have given us I created a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/Pnxbn/) of what the the code is expecting the html to look like and how this would work let me know if that helps you out

HTML

```
<div class="click">
    <div id="start-chat">start chat</div>
</div>
```

and your code

```
$('#start-chat').live("click",function(){
    $(this).parent('.click').append('<div id="forclick">some data inside it</div>');
});
```